# Powershell - How to remove trailing spaces from a list of groups a user is in

Tags: powershell

I've copied/created a script to get all the members of a group that a user is part of, including nested groups. However, my output isn't quite the way I want it.

It goes in one of two ways. Either it outputs as one big string, which looks nice, but has trailing spaces on each line so I cannot simply copy and paste it into AD. Or if I change the Out-String to use -stream, it comes out as a garbled mess, but may allow me to trim the spaces.

I currently have the output going into a TextBox in a simple GUI.

```
Function Get-ADUserNestedGroups {
Param
(
    [string]$DistinguishedName,
    [array]$Groups = @()
)

#Get the AD object, and get group membership.
$ADObject = Get-ADObject -Filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$DistinguishedName'" -Properties memberOf, DistinguishedName;

#If object exists.
If($ADObject)
{
    #Enummurate through each of the groups.
    Foreach($GroupDistinguishedName in $ADObject.memberOf)
    {
        #Get member of groups from the enummerated group.
        $CurrentGroup = Get-ADObject -Filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$GroupDistinguishedName'" -Properties memberOf, DistinguishedName;
   
        #Check if the group is already in the array.
        If(($Groups | Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -eq $GroupDistinguishedName}).Count -eq 0)
        {
            #Add group to array.
            $Groups +=  $CurrentGroup;

            #Get recursive groups.      
            $Groups = Get-ADUserNestedGroups -DistinguishedName $GroupDistinguishedName -Groups $Groups;
        }
    }
}

#Return groups.
Return $Groups;
}

 Function Display-UserGroups {

#Get all groups.
$Groups = Get-ADUserNestedGroups -DistinguishedName (Get-ADUser -Identity $userSAM).DistinguishedName;

$ResultsTextBox.Text = $Groups | Select-Object Name| Sort-Object name | Out-String
```

The output with the first way looks like:

Group Name1(Eight Spaces Here)

Group Name2(Eight Spaces Here)

The output with the second way looks like:

Group Name1GroupName2GroupName3

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like you are doing more than what is posted here for your output attempts. You could trim your strings and then add line breaks for the text box: ```($Groups | Select -Expand Name | Sort).Trim() -join "`n"```.

Comment: This worked! I did have to use a  backticked "r" along with the n.

Thanks @AdminOfThings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim your output, which can easily be done with [String.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1) method. However, it can only be applied against strings. `$Groups` will be an array of `ADObject` types. You will need to return the `Name` values of those objects and apply the `Trim()` method to the values.

```
($Groups | Select -Expand Name | Sort).Trim() -join "`r`n"
```

Comment: The extra spaces were likely coming from the default table output of the single property (Name) objects produced by `Select-Object`.  The `-ExapandProperty` parameter is altering that behavior, creating a flat array of strings.  This is similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820290/4749264) except I unrolled the Name property from the `$Groups` variable. I think `.Trim()` is unnecessary!  The name property is unlikely to have trailing spaces on its own. I don't think AD even allows trailing spaces for names.

Comment: @Steven it is possible. I know that querying AD objects, personally, never gives me this issue. There is a lot of unnecessary code being executed in the original post and something is mangling normally, clean objects. I only added this answer because the poster said my comment fixed the issue.

Comment: I wasn't being critical.  Somewhat wondering if we should refine beyond the scope of the question? I agree with you, I made mods in my own answer. I'm certain of the padding issue though, it's obscure but known.  And, [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc776019(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) confirms no leading /trailing space allowed. Sorry I just thought it was relevant to clarify. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$Groups += $CurrentGroup.trimEnd()` to add the value with the trailing spaces trimmed.

A few other methods you might want to research

```
.trim()      # Trim leading and trailing
.trimEnd()   # Trim trailing
.trimStart() # Trim leading
```

Comment: `TrimEnd()` belongs to String class. The returned objects are ADObject types. I think the idea is good but a conversion must be done first.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is being caused by PowerShell's formatting system.  `Select-Object` is returning single property (Name) objects.  PowerShell outputs that as a table, which may have some padding.  `Out-String` is keeping that padding which is why it was reflecting in your final output...

The name property of the group is already a string.  There's no need to use `Out-String` if you unroll the Name property from your `$Groups` variable/collection.

With some other adjustments for readability & testing.  Below will emit a single string with each group on a new line.  That should be paste-able into AD, by which I think you meant Active Directory User & Computers.

```
Function Get-ADUserNestedGroups
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$DistinguishedName,
        [array]$Groups = @()
    )
    
    # Get the AD object, and get group membership.
    $ADObject = Get-ADObject $DistinguishedName -Properties memberOf, DistinguishedName
    
    # If object exists.
    If( $ADObject )
    {
        # Enummurate through each of the groups.
        Foreach( $GroupDistinguishedName in $ADObject.memberOf )
        {
            # Get member of groups from the enummerated group.
            $CurrentGroup = Get-ADObject $GroupDistinguishedName -Properties memberOf, DistinguishedName
       
            # Check if the group is already in the array.
            If( $Groups.DistinguishedName -notcontains $GroupDistinguishedName )
            {
                # Add group to array.
                $Groups +=  $CurrentGroup
    
                # Get recursive groups.      
                $Groups = Get-ADUserNestedGroups -DistinguishedName $GroupDistinguishedName -Groups $Groups
            }
        }
    }
    
    # Return groups.
    Return $Groups
    }
    
$userSAM = 'UserName'

# Get all groups.
$Groups = Get-ADUserNestedGroups -DistinguishedName (Get-ADUser -Identity $userSAM).DistinguishedName
($Groups.Name | Sort-Object) -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Among the secondary changes you'll see I removed the `-Filter` parameter in a few places.  The DistinguishedName can be used as the `-Identity` parameter so no need to filter.

Also, where you were checking if the `$Groups` collection already had the current group I used the `-notContains` operator instead.  That should be faster then repeatedly iterating the collection with `|Where{...}` The code is also shorter and more readable.

> Note: if we reverse the operands we could use `-notin` which may look
> nicer still

An aside; You should avoid appending arrays with `+=`. Doing so can causes performance problems because it creates a new array any copies the contents over. The best way to deal with this is to allow PowerShell to accumulate the results for you.  If you must do the append directly, look into using Array Lists.  There's a lot information on this, just google it.